# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this2.context.router.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router

I tried to redirect my page after clicking submit button and for that, my onSubmit method looks like;

```
onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if (this.isValid()){
      this.setState({ errors: {}, isLoading: true });
      this.props.userSignupRequest(this.state).then(
        () => {
          this.context.router.push('/');
        },
        ( data ) => this.setState({ errors: data.response.data, isLoading: false })
      );
    }
  }
```

Also my **propTypes** and **contextTypes**;

```
SignupForm.propTypes = {
  userSignupRequest: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

SignupForm.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

I don't know why but it keeps showing an error and not redirecting. 
Also I tried **browserHistory.push('/')** and it didn't work either.

Error I took was;

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this2.context.router.push is not a function
    at props.userSignupRequest.then._this2.setState.errors
```

As I said, I also tried **browserHistory** like;

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
```

and onSubmit method;

```
  onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if (this.isValid()){
      this.setState({ errors: {}, isLoading: true });
      this.props.userSignupRequest(this.state).then(
        () => {
          browserHistory.push('/');
        },
        ( data ) => this.setState({ errors: data.response.data, isLoading: false })
      );
    }
  }
```

My router also is like;

```
const router = (<Provider store={store}>
                  <Router history={browserHistory}>{routes}</Router>
                </Provider>);
```

Error it throws is the same as the other one.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at props.userSignupRequest.then._this2.setState.errors
```

If anything more is needed, please add below and I'll edit my post.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of react and react-router that you use

Comment: react: 15.5.3 react-router: 4.0.0 @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: For react 15.5.3 React.Proptypes is deprecated . Install `prop-types` and import it like `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'` and  use `router: PropTypes.object.isRequired`. Let me know if that helps

Comment: I already declared proptypes just above of contextTypes. Didn't write it on my post but if you say, doesn't matter if I declared propTypes and I already need to install prop-types, then I'll give it a try. **(I edited my post and added propTypes)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the code below.

```
  this.context.router.push('/');
```

In react-router versions greater and equal to 4.0.0, this push method is moved below "**history**" method and its new version seems like;

```
  this.context.router.history.push('/');
```

This works fine and solved my problem.

**NOTE**

You can see what I'm saying from '**React**' tab of your browser.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMpey.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a constructor? or may i see your code block? I am having same issue

Comment: To what extent do you have the same issue? I mean, I can share my constructor but I don't think it is relevant for this problem. What is your problem? Maybe I can help you if you share a detailed information about your problem on a new post. @canperk

Comment: My problem is I have a route definition App class and it is working. And I have another OptionMenu class and there are some links to navigate. When I click to <Link to="/" /> browser route is changing but page html is not being updated. History counter is changing on every click.

Comment: I don't think our problems are identical but you may wanna surround your <Link> tag around a hardcoded label. I mean, you can change it like;

<Link to={'/'}>Home</Link>

or something like that.

Comment: I have been struggling with the latest versions of react and react-router-dom. This code works perfectly for mine issue. Thank you